# count only active products in magento

Tags: magento

I just want to display only active products in my list. i have a script that count all the enable and disable products but i want to count only active products.
my code is:-

```
  <?php 
    $_categories = Mage::getBlockSingleton('catalog/navigation'); 
    foreach ($_categories->getStoreCategories() as $_category) { 
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category'); 
    $category->load($_category->getId()); 
    $subcategories = explode(',', $category->getChildren()); 
    $_count = is_array($subcategories)?count($subcategories):$subcategories->count(); 
    $pcount = array();
    foreach ($subcategories as $subcategoryId) { 
        $subcategory = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($subcategoryId);
        if($subcategory->getIsActive()){ 
        $pcount[] = $subcategory->getProductCount();  
        }
    }
    }
```

i tried in if condition getIsActive but it can't work it get all the enable and disable products, suggest me where i some make changes to count only active products.

Comment: In this code, you are checking if the category is active or not, not products. They have a 'status' enabled or disabled.

Comment: How to get active products ?????

Comment: products are not "active", they are either "enabled" or "disabled". I can suggest you something if you want to count enabled products.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the active products independent of the category they are in you can do this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes()) //add the attributes visible in product list to the collection
            ->addMinimalPrice() //add the prices to the collection
            ->addFinalPrice()
            ->addTaxPercents()
            ->addUrlRewrite(); //add the url rewrites to the collection
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection); //filter only active products
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection); //filter only visible in catalog products
```

then just loop through the collection and do something with each product

```
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    //do something with $product
}
```

If you want to get the number of products in the collection do this:

```
$size = $collection->getSize();
```

If you want to do the above but for a single category :

```
$categoryId = 10;//replace with own id.
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes()) //add the attributes visible in product list to the collection
                ->addMinimalPrice() //add the prices to the collection
                ->addFinalPrice()
                ->addTaxPercents()
                ->addUrlRewrite($categoryId); //add the url rewrites to the collection
$collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($collection); //filter only active products
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection); //filter only visible in catalog products
```

Answer (score 2):

`addVisibleFilterToCollection` and `addSaleableFilterToCollection` are deprecated, and will do nothing in newer versions of Magento.
You should use:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('in'=>Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->getSaleableStatusIds()));
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array('in'=>Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds()));
```

Comment: Might be worth proposing as an edit to Marius's answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your foreach loop, you need to edit something like:

```
$collection = $category->getProductCollection()
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq'=>'1'));
$pcount = $collection->count();
```

It should do the thing you want. If not, then let me know.
Cheers!